# delete record from tableView - beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to delete a row from a tableView, and the tableview should get updated, How can i program this?

my work so far;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

        [tableView endUpdates];     
        [tableView beginUpdates];
///??????????

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];

    }
}
```

My table is populated using an `NSArray` called `peopleList`, so how can i delete a record and update my table view ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the first `endUpdates` call.

Between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` you should also remove the object from your `peopleList` array, so that both the table view and the array have 1 less element when you call `endUpdates`. Other than that, it should work fine.

Comment: SO is it something like this ??? [tableView beginUpdates];
  //DELETE FROM LIST
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];

Comment: I also get this exception `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'` any clue?

Comment: You need to remove the object from `peopleList` where you've written `DELETE FROM LIST` to fix that exception.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an NSMutableArray as storage instead of an NSArray.

Just updated your storage - in the case of an NSMutableArray (instead of the NSArray you mentioned) you just need to call removeObjectAtIndex before you call removeObjectsAtIndex.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {

        ...

        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSLog(@"delete section: %d rol: %d", [indexPath indexAtPosition:0], [indexPath indexAtPosition:1]);
        [_items removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        ...
    }   
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your table view's begin/end update block, you'll want to copy your peopleList to a mutable array, delete the record, then set peopleList to be an immutable copy of the changed array.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

// Sending -mutableCopy to an NSArray returns an NSMutableArray
NSMutableArray *peopleListCopy = [self.peopleList mutableCopy]; 

// Delete the appropriate object
[peopleListCopy removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Sending -copy to an NSMutableArray returns an immutable NSArray.
// Autoreleasing because the setter for peopleList will retain the array.
// -autorelease is unnecessary if you're using Automatic Reference Counting.
self.peopleList = [[peopleListCopy copy] autorelease]; 

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[tableView endUpdates];
```